# 4D MRI image recognition with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm making a CNN in tensorflow with 3D MRI's in NiFTI format. I tried to follow the tutorial on the TensorFlow website, but this tutorial only seems to be working on 3D images (length x width x rgb), however, my images have the shape length x width x depth x greyscale (256, 256, 44, 1).

I deleted the last dimension:

```
for i in range(len (x)): 
    result = x[i][:, :, :, 0]
```

Which gives me an array in the shape (256, 256, 44) and the model works. But I'm quite sure this is not the right solution because this way some data get lost.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: why do you think there is some data getting lost? You last dim size is 1. You can think of [[0,1,2]] with [0,1,2].

Comment: I was assuming that I simply deleted some data, but this definitely changes my perspective. Thank you!

Comment: can you share a sample image of your data-set, so I can help you, I guess the first dimensions are the spatial resolution, while the last two are slice number and frame number in case of 4D images (+time), for Deep Learning you need to extract each slice separately if you are dealing with 2D convolution or you can extract 3D images if you are dealing with 3D convolution.